# jquery - how to find from nextAll

Tags: jquery, html

I couldn't find an answer that fits exactly in this. I have the following html.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="item" id="item1"></div>
   <div class="item" id="item2"></div>
   <div class="pl"></div>
   <div class="item" id="item3"></div>
   <div class="item" id="item4"></div>
   <div class="item" id="item5"></div>
   <div class="item" id="item6"></div>
</div>
```

This is the what I am doing in middle of my code.

```
var result = $("#item1").nextAll().slice(0,3);
console.log(result.find(".pl").length);
```

The final output seems to return 0. But I expect it to return 1.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) because `result` refers an elements set that includes the `.pl` element

```
var result = $("#item1").nextAll().slice(0,3);
console.log(result.filter(".pl").length);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cc8zd/)

Comment: Thanks this works. filter() is what I want, not find().

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you want:

```
var result = $("#item1").nextAll('.pl').length;
console.log(result); // 1
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JN8RK/)**

Comment: No I still want the other values. I want anything next to #item1. but out of the result I want to check if there is any div with class "pl"